# Swift - Integrate GameCenter to use leaderboards

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, game-center

I am making a game in Swift. I want to be able to post the users' score using GameCenter, so that scores from all my users' can be seen. However, I have spent the past day trying to figure out how to do this, but I haven't found any helpful instructions.

I am pretty new to iOS programming, and Swift, and of the very little amount of information on this subject, it's all written in Objective-C.

Can anyone help me integrate GameCenter into my app, so that I can post users scores to the leaderboards for people to see?

EDIT: I have already created a GameCenter leaderboard on iTunesConnect.

EDIT 2: I have tried following this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-game-kit-framework/ and converting it to Swift. I have converted this:

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer {
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
        if (viewController != nil) {
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else{
            if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated) {
                _gameCenterEnabled = YES;

                // Get the default leaderboard identifier.
                [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {

                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                    else{
                        _leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
                    }
                }];
            }

            else {
                _gameCenterEnabled = NO;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

into this:

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer() {
    var localPlayer : GKLocalPlayer!
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : MenuViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if viewController != nil {
            self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            if localPlayer.authenticated {
                self.gameCenterEnabled = true

                localPlayer.loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler({ (leaderboardIdentifier : String!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        println(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else {
                        self.leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier
                    }
                })

            } else {
                self.gameCenterEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it crashes on this line:

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController : UIViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
```

The Error message is:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I can't believe how hard this is!

Comment: "and of the very little amount of information on this subject, it's all written in Objective-C." - so what? the API is all the same, difference is only in syntax.

Comment: If you are new to it, i recommend buying a few books and learning how to use the code properly. I learnt how to use leaderboards in the games book from Ray Wenderlich. It is in objective-c, but as said above, it is incredibly easy to convert over as it is merely a syntax change

Comment: Okay, I understand that. I've just tried for past hour trying to convert an Objective-C tutorial to Swift, and it's incredibly difficult, especially for a beginner like me! See my edit.

Comment: Hi I just read your post about game center. I'm trying to integer it in my game with swift too. I'm not a really good programer and it's impossible for me to translate Objective-C to swift as you did. I read the very good tutorial you gave but as you said it's in objective C. So do you know where I can found all the code and explanation in swift? Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 5):

Your specific issue has nothing to do with Game Center and is happening because you have the line `var localPlayer : GKLocalPlayer!`.

You're declaring an implicitly unwrapped optional and then using it right away. It's value is nil in the subsequent line when you try to set `localPlayer.authenticateHandler`.

Instead you should instantiate GKLocalPlayer like so:

```
var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()
```

Note that there are currently issues with Game Center and Swift. Your code is going to work but `localPlayer.authenticated` never gets set to true. This issue is tracked here:

http://www.openradar.me/17825348

Credit to: http://www.stuarticus.net/blog/2014/7/game-center-authentication-and-swift
for filing the radar ticket.

Comment: This issue seems to be resolved as of Xcode 6 beta 6

Answer (score 2):

You can use that, I create a simple class for iOS game center in github
**Easy Class Game Center Swift**
https://github.com/DaRkD0G/Easy-Game-Center-Swift